# Side menu controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, view, side-menu

I am working on a YouTube project and the problem is that I want to add a side menu and I know how to do that. However, when I press a cell I don't want it to load a new view. Instead, I want it to update my table view because I don't want 20 different views that do nearly the same thing and just load different videos. Any idea how I can achieve my goal?

I was thinking of using this side menu: https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Coding in swift

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom class that does all the tableview initialization as a BaseClass and make childClass for different Menus. Instead of:

```
class menu1: UITableViewController {
}

class menu2: UITableViewController {
}
```

Use this:

```
class BaseTableViewController: UITableViewController {
}

class menu1: BaseTableViewController {
}

class menu2: BaseTableViewController {
}
```

Reuse the class and make a fetch function content for cell with customizable input parameters. You could refer letsbuildthatapp youtube tutorial series for reference. It has a [letsbuildyoutube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Xv1mJvwXok&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JGKdVUtA5xds1zcyzsz7HLj) app series.

Comment: could you explain more please I have made the side menu but I don't know how to make so I for example press a cell to reload my view with new videos ? don't know how to implant it

Comment: What you achieve by clicking a cell can be triggered by calling it in 'viewDidLoad' or call the reload view after data fetching is completed